# Which coroutine is sequential?

Tags: python, mqtt, python-asyncio

I'm studying the HBMQTT docs at [hbmqtt](https://hbmqtt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/references/mqttclient.html) and there are 2 functions which do the same thing, basically to publish 3 messages to an MQTT broker:

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def test_coro():
    C = MQTTClient()
    yield from C.connect('mqtt://test.mosquitto.org/')
    tasks = [
        asyncio.ensure_future(C.publish('a/b', b'TEST MESSAGE WITH QOS_0')),
        asyncio.ensure_future(C.publish('a/b', b'TEST MESSAGE WITH QOS_1', qos=QOS_1)),
        asyncio.ensure_future(C.publish('a/b', b'TEST MESSAGE WITH QOS_2', qos=QOS_2)),
    ]
    yield from asyncio.wait(tasks)
    logger.info("messages published")
    yield from C.disconnect()


@asyncio.coroutine
def test_coro2():
    try:
        C = MQTTClient()
        ret = yield from C.connect('mqtt://test.mosquitto.org:1883/')
        message = yield from C.publish('a/b', b'TEST MESSAGE WITH QOS_0', qos=QOS_0)
        message = yield from C.publish('a/b', b'TEST MESSAGE WITH QOS_1', qos=QOS_1)
        message = yield from C.publish('a/b', b'TEST MESSAGE WITH QOS_2', qos=QOS_2)
        #print(message)
        logger.info("messages published")
        yield from C.disconnect()
    except ConnectException as ce:
        logger.error("Connection failed: %s" % ce)
        asyncio.get_event_loop().stop()
```

The docs go on to describe them as:

> test_coro() publish 3 messages in sequence. test_coro2() publishes the same message asynchronously.

This makes no sense since I've also been studying `asyncio` and as I understand it `ensure_future()` schedules tasks to run asynchronously whereas `yield from` seems to serve the same purpose as `await` and thus each of those statements will simply block till the task is completed. So the description should be the other way round. Am I right or missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the names of the coroutines are swapped and should be the other way round.

Furthermore: the code is outdated.
i.e.

- There is no need to mark the functions as coroutines with such decorator anymore,, just use the `async` keyword.
- use `await` instead of `yield from`